# How to configure bluetooth to stop it from starting by default?

Tags: windows-7, bluetooth

Each time i boot my window, it also starts bluetooth by default. I dont use it much frequently. Is there any option by which my bluetooth does not come up by default on startup.
I am using samsung laptop, window 7 OS.

Answer (score 3):

Click Start;
Type msconfig;
Click Startup;
Uncheck the blootooth device/ application from there.
Hope you are good to go.

Comment: Yuck. MSConfig is intended for _temporary use_ for diagnosing problems, not turning things on and off instead of dealing with it properly. :)

Answer (score 3):

I rarely use bluetooth on my Win 7 laptop so I just disable it in the device manager. It only takes a few seconds to enable it again when I need it.

Click Start > Type Control Panel > click control panel > then click System > on the left side click Device Manager

Your bluetooth module will be in there under bluetooth radios; just right-click and choose disable. Repeat the steps to enable when you need it.

[More info here](http://www.thetechhub.com/2010/12/disable-bluetooth-in-windows-7-how-to.html).

Comment: This is a good solution. I have bluetooth speakers and every time I wake my computer, it steals the connection from my wife's kindle. It was kind of funny at first, but quickly became annoying. This is much better as I can simply enable it when I want to use the speakers, without yanking it when I don't want it.

Comment: Win7 has a taskbar widget that you can use now. Makes turning bluetooth on and off take seconds.